# select latest row in mysql but primary is varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this ( pid is varchar ):

```
| pid | name |
| p1  | a    |
| p10 | b    |
| p11 | c    |
| p2  | d    |
| p3  | e    |
```

I want to select latest inserted row ( p11 ), but the selected one is p3, while I want to select p11. I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(pid) as LASTID FROM product
```

How can I write a query to return p11?

Comment: For an easy life, don't store the 'p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `p` and convert it to a number before calculating the maximum.

```
SELECT CONCAT('p', MAX(REPLACE(pid, 'p', '') + 0)) AS lastid
FROM product
```